# Output exception in terminal

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

when I type this command:

frank@frank-PC:~$ aslkfd

output in terminal:

aslkfd\uff1a\u672a\u627e\u5230\u547d\u4ee4

I don't know why...can someone help me?

Comment: `aslkfd：未找到命令` — that is, "command not found".

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge aslkfd is not a linux/UNIX command.

Following command give you path of this file.

> which  aslkfd

If it is an executable available in server as command you will get the path of it by executing above command.

If above command don't give you a path, your problem description is wrong and you should get an output as 'command not found'.

Since it is not a standard command, you have to figure out what it is else check with your colleagues if it is an internally developed command.